# Bitewise And Operator

Tags: c#, .net, operators

Wondering about the &= operator. And how it works. From what i have gathered it finds out the last "bit" and returns it. Like for example 10 in binary is 101**0**. So it will return **0**.

What i cannot wrap my head around is how its doing that. What is the process that leads to that result?

```
using System;

namespace MyApplication
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      int x = 5;
      x &= 3;
      Console.WriteLine(x);  
     }
  }  //Output is 1
}
```

Code from https://www.w3schools.com/cs/trycs.php?filename=demo_oper_ass7

Comment: 5 in binary is 0101 (i.e. 4 + 1). 3 in binary is 0011 (i.e. 2 +1). So the value that they both share is 0001 (i.e. 1). This isn't unique to C#, this is how bitwise AND works in any programming language. Please read about [Bitwise operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). You can also refer to [truth tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction_(AND)) for the individual result of combining any two bits with a specific operation.

Answer (score 3):

If you consider the values as binary, I think it will be clearer how it works:

| Decimal | Binary |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | 0101 |
| 3 | 0011 |
| 1 | 0001 |

Bitwise AND will operate on each pair of bits in turn based on their position. The following truth table demonstrates what happens given two **bit values**, represented by P and Q:

| p | q | p ^ q |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |

As you can see, only where both P and Q are 1 will a 1 be the result. In all other situations 0 will be the result.

I'll break 5 and 3 down into their individual bits in the table below, with the decimal column indicating what decimal value each bit represents. As you can see, 5 is 4 + 1 and 3 is 2 + 1. Applying a bitwise AND, we can see the result in the R column:

| dec | 5 (p) | 3 (q) | R (p ^ q) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0 | 1 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

The result of p ^ q where for (p = 5, q = 3) is `0001` (1 in decimal).

You can read more about Bitwise operations [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) and see more truth tables [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_conjunction_(AND)).